# Jacquet modules in representations of finite groups

Tags: modules, representation-theory

The representations of general linear group over finite field have been generalized to some analogous matrix groups (possibly infinite).

I recently came across a concept of Jacquet module which is defined on [here on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquet_module); I am trying to understand it through representations of finite groups.

Can anybody explain with an example where the Jacquet modules have importance in representations of *finite* groups? (I am familiar with basic representation theory of finite groups - say Isaacs book.)

Comment: For finite groups in characteristic $0$ it is just the same as the invariant submodule.

Comment: As also mentioned on that wiki page, the term is mainly used in some special cases (it mentions reductive groups over $p$-adic fields, but it is not used in the nearby field of reductive groups in positive characteristic, or at least I have not seen it).